# Could not resolve property of @OneToMany child table (@JoinColumn)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am getting the above error when trying to run a custom query. I understand that with hibernate, you need to map to the `entity` names (not the `column` names). However, in the case of a `@OneToMany`, I don't have the column in the child. Let me explain with a simple example (I've removed all other columns and methods):

```
@Query("SELECT ch.randomColumnHere FROM Parent pa INNER JOIN Child ch ON pa.id = ch.parent_id")
```

**Parent.class**

```
@Entity(name="Parent")
@Table(name="parent")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "parent_id_seq", sequenceName = "parent_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parent_id_seq")
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<Child> children;

}
```

**Child.class**

```
@Entity(name="Child")
@Table(name="child")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class Child {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "child_id_seq", sequenceName = "child_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "child_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="randomcolumnhere")
    private Double randomColumnHere;
}
```

I get the following exception:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: parent_id`

I understand that there is no `field` called `parent_id` in the `Child entity`. How can I get around this? Since the only 'reference' to the `parent_id` column is the `@JoinColumn` of the `Parent` class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the easiest to get around this is to define a @ManyToOne relation in the Child class. Then specify mappedBy in the parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add relationship in child class as follow and change query accordingly.

```
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent p;

    @Query("SELECT ch.randomColumnHere FROM Parent pa INNER JOIN Child ch ON pa.id = ch.p.id")
```

Answer (score 0):

HQL queries use entities and their associations. The fact that the association uses a join table or not is not important for HQL: you navigate through associations and Hibernate does the appropriate translation to SQL.

SELECT ch.randomColumnHere FROM Parent pa INNER JOIN pa.children;